# Erlang: query more than 1000 LDAP elements using "eldap" library

Tags: erlang, ldap, ejabberd

I am using ejabberd, a jabber daemon written in Erlang. It is connected to our Active Directory using its LDAP interface and Erlang's eldap library.

Everything works so far with a small limitation causing a big problem:

- A normal LDAP query receives **up to 1000 elements** and then stops.
- We have more than 1000 employees and therefore receiver only a part of the whole query

Using [*nix' `ldapsearch` tool](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapsearch), I can use the option `-E pr=1000/noprompt` for receiving multiple pages (which finally get concatenated to a single one) without any limitation.

How could I use this function using Erlang's eldap library?
I already read through the [source code](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/eldap.erl), but don't seem to find anything obvious.

*#erlang had some nice ideas about this:*

> emauton: It looks to me like you're out of luck. Paged results are supplied by an LDAP extension, described in http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2696.txt. If you look at ldapsearch, you can see this being added to the query at http://goo.gl/lemNOS
>
> emauton: Reading through the eldap source, this extension doesn't make an appearance. The good news is that it shouldn't be too hard to add, I think, by messing about with the 'controls' part of the LDAPMessage.
>
> emauton: You should be able to set up your request according to the RFC using the right controlType & contents (referencing the ldapsearch code) and use it to make a paginating version of eldap:search

Comment: For which feature of ejabberd does that limitation cause an issue to you ? For example, it should not be a problem with authentication.

Comment: the issues are happening while using **mod_shared_roster_ldap**. While querying the LDAP for all empoyees I run into the 1000-entries-limit.

Comment: Are you expecting to have a shared rosters with more than 1000 people in it ? Roster are not intended to be a company directory.

Comment: This is exactly what we want, though.

Comment: Actually, I do not know how many users you have but you will be generating far too many presence. It will be a problem for the clients, especially if you plan connection on mobile. My view is that you should think about another design and not do the simplest approach just because it is easier to implement.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up. We just want to overcome the problem of having to add every single contact one needs in our 1.2k-head-company. It would have practical benefits when you can just browser your messenger and find the person you need grouped by department.

Comment: What about Jabber directory protocol ? It seems more suited for that need. You can search it and have a UI to start chatting with someone with a single click. Note that you do not have to be in each other roster to chat. You would need to write a LDAP backend to Jabber directory, but you will probably to download the whole corporate directory on each login from a user.

Comment: I have not been able to find anything about a Jabber Directory Protocol. I assume this will fill a kind of catalog for contacts. But is it possible to use it with any jabber client or is it application-specific? Seems like Jitsi also included a kind of LDAP lookup/directory.

Comment: I think a standard client can use server disco feature and XMPP forms to query it.